# Delete message over than 99 in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Ok. I search many things to delete over than 99 messages. But I cannot make it. I downed limit 99 to 5 because of test.

**My code is**

> What is wrong?
>
> Command is " !clear (amount) "

```
start1: while (true) {
  if (amount <= 5) {
    message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).then(() => {
      amount = 0;
    })
    break;
  } else if (amount > 5) {
    message.channel.messages.fetch({
        limit: 5
      })
      .then(fetched => {
        message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched, true)
      });
    amount = amount - 5;
    if (amount !== 0) continue start1;

  }
}
```

Comment: Is the while loop necessary?

Comment: Yes. Actually, It need loop cause to delete limit messages when amount over to limit. Bulkdelete can delete max 99, And i set it in 5.

Comment: but why are you using ``while (true)``?  This sets up an infinite loop.  You have no exit condition.

Comment: `message.channel.messages.fetch` fetch deleted messages too, so 100 i`ts max

Comment: I tried another loop like do{}while or for(var i=0~~~) I think message.fetch is in loop, It didnt fetch new messages

Comment: Anyone cant solve problem..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
async () => {
  let fetched;
  do {
    fetched = await channel.fetchMessages({limit: 100});
    message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched);
  }
  while(fetched.size >= 5);
}
```